# MAX function not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have a simple query that has me confused. It appears the MAX function isn't working, but I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong.

As it is written below, I'm getting 2 records, rather than just one. Each record has different FHUK01 values, so I put in the MAX function to pull out the larger of the two, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT MAX(CRPDTA.F4981.FHUK01) AS "UID",
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHSHPN,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHUOM,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1
FROM CRPDTA.f4981
WHERE crpdta.f4981.FHSHPN=4577085
AND CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1 = 'DIS'
GROUP BY CRPDTA.F4981.FHUK01,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHSHPN,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHUOM,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1;
```

Sample Query Output:

```
UID     FHSHPN  FHRTDQ  FHUOM   FHCGC1

7502828 4577085 630000  MI  DIS

7502827 4577085 0       DIS
```

Comment: I've got to ask. What's the deal your your column and table names?

Comment: @Zane You know, in case they get hacked.

Comment: @Zane They're "CRP"-y. :)

Comment: @Zane looks like COTS ... i dealt with some ***awful*** table names in an ERP once.

Comment: it's an enterprise system db, and the columns are very cryptic.  outside of my control.  lol

Comment: the answer is: you're getting multiple rows because there are multiple grouping sets as evidenced in your data (particularly with regards to the values in `FHRTDQ` and `FHUOM`). you should post what you want the data to look like so that you can get the correct answer

Comment: IF you are expecting the answer to be '7502828' then take out these lines GROUP BY CRPDTA.F4981.FHUK01,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHSHPN,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHUOM,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1;

Comment: `FHUOM` is `NULL` in second record, try removing them in `GROUP BY` and also, you apply `MAX()` in a grouped column, which is obviously no use. In case you may need to remove `FHUK01` also from `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 2):

You're `GROUPing BY` the column that you're trying to `MAX`:

```
GROUP BY CRPDTA.F4981.FHUK01
```

You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: i removed that line, and still get 2 records.  this is weird.  :/

Comment: That's because you're grouping by some things.  So you'll get a MAX for each `group by` "group".  Specifically, you'll get a line for each combination of FHRTDQ and FHUOM values that exists in the DB (where FHSHPN=4577085 AND FHCGC1 = 'DIS').

Comment: no. he's grouping by multiple columns that have different data in them which is creating multiple grouping sets.

Answer (score 0):

As swasheck mentioned in his post since you are having multiple grouping sets in your query, you will get multiple rows only.

If, you wish to get data corresponding to the maximum FHUK01. Probably what you need is something like:

```
 Select  CRPDTA.F4981.FHUK01,
         CRPDTA.F4981.FHSHPN,
         CRPDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,
         CRPDTA.F4981.FHUOM,
         CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1
         from crpdata.f4981
        where f4981.fhuk01= (SELECT MAX(CRPDTA.F4981.FHUK01) 
                             FROM CRPDTA.f4981
                             WHERE crpdta.f4981.FHSHPN=4577085
                             AND CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1 = 'DIS');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
SELECT MAX(CRPDTA.F4981.FHUK01) AS "UID",
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHSHPN,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHUOM,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1
FROM CRPDTA.f4981
WHERE crpdta.f4981.FHSHPN=4577085
AND CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1 = 'DIS'
GROUP BY 
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHSHPN,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHUOM,
  CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the row having maximum value of FHUK01 for given FHSHPN and FHCGC1.

```
with tab(FHUK01, FHSHPN, FHRTDQ, FHUOM, FHCGC1, RN) as
(select CRPDTA.F4981.FHUK01,
        CRPDTA.F4981.FHSHPN,
        CRPDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,
        CRPDTA.F4981.FHUOM,
        CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1,
        row_number() over (partition by crpdta.f4981.FHSHPN, CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1 order by CRPDTA.F4981.FHUK01 desc) rn
   from CRPDTA.f4981
  where crpdta.f4981.FHSHPN=4577085
    AND CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1 = 'DIS')
select FHUK01, FHSHPN, FHRTDQ, FHUOM, FHCGC1
  from tab
 where rn = 1;
```

Comment: my original posted query was actually just the inner part of a merge query i was trying to build.  this method worked for me.  thanks a million.  :)

Answer (score 0):

my original post was only the inner part of a merge query I was trying to build.  I did finally get it to work using San's suggestion...

```
MERGE INTO CRPDTA.F4941 DST
USING (WITH TAB (RSSHPN,RSRSSN,RSDSTN,RSUMD1,RSADDJ,FHUK01,FHSHPN,FHRTDQ,FHUOM,FHCGC1,RN) AS
(SELECT CRPDTA.F4941.RSSHPN,
CRPDTA.F4941.RSRSSN,
CRPDTA.F4941.RSDSTN,
CRPDTA.F4941.RSUMD1,
CRPDTA.F4941.RSADDJ,
CRPDTA.F4981.FHUK01,
CRPDTA.F4981.FHSHPN,
CRPDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,
CRPDTA.F4981.FHUOM,
CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CRPDTA.F4941.RSSHPN, CRPDTA.F4941.RSRSSN, CRPDTA.F4981.FHSHPN, CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1 ORDER BY CRPDTA.F4981.FHUK01 DESC) RN
FROM CRPDTA.F4941
INNER JOIN CRPDTA.F4981
ON CRPDTA.F4941.RSSHPN = CRPDTA.F4981.FHSHPN
WHERE CRPDTA.F4941.RSDSTN = 0
AND CRPDTA.F4941.RSADDJ > 110365
AND CRPDTA.F4981.FHCGC1 = 'DIS')

SELECT * FROM TAB
WHERE RN = 1) SRC
ON (DST.RSSHPN = SRC.FHSHPN)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET DST.RSDSTN = ROUND(SRC.FHRTDQ/10000,0), DST.RSUMD1 = SRC.FHUOM;
```